# Does iTunes have an SDK or API to use?

Tags: macos, sdk, itunes, apple-music

Is there a way to import to apple music playlist without having the mp3 for the song, that apple music will automatically find and allow you to play?

OR

Is there anyway to add a playlist to iTunes Apple Music without having the song and getting iTunes Match to find the song from the importing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time flies! MusicKit from Apple might be your best bet.

https://developer.apple.com/musickit/